# case insensitive Foreign Key PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, case-sensitive, postgresql-9.3

Need to know if I can add a case insensitive foreign key constraint to a table in PostgreSQL. I am converting a DB from MySQL to PostgreSQL. The foreign keys were already created in MySQL and I did not face any problems because MySQL was not case sensitive. When I load all the data from MySQL to PostgreSQL and then try to add foreign keys to the tables, I get an error in Postgres. For example:

Table A had 2 columns:
ID (int) and Name(varchar(25))

`Entry1: ID  = 1 , Name = 'America'
Entry2: ID = 2 , Name = 'Canada'`

Table B had 2 columns:
ID (int) and Name(varchar(25))

`Entry1: ID(int) = 10 , Name(Varchar(25)) = 'AmeRiCA'
Entry1: ID = 1 , Name = 'Canada'`

in MySQL, the foreign key was created between Table A and Table B on column "Name", however in Postgres, because of the case sensitive nature I get an error.

I do not have an option to Alter the table and change Varchar to citext. is there anyway I can define a case insensitive foreign key in PG.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is interesting but I'm curious... Why would you prefer to use the name as key (to create the fk) instead of the id ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos -- Well thats the same question which came to my mind when I started looking at this DB. This DB was created already and handed over to me. So, do you think there is anyway to accomplish this task?

Comment: I think that without the citext option you would have to create a trigger before insert/update/delete to check if that rows exists using lower or upper functions. I know, its uggly!

Answer (score 2):

By far the best thing you can do is to correct your data. For example like this:

```
update A set name=initcap(name) where name<>initcap(name);
update B set name=initcap(name) where name<>initcap(name);
```

If it's unacceptable then you can create additional column in both tables, say `name_lower`, which would be automatically set to `lower(name)` using a trigger:

```
create or replace function name_lower_trigger() returns trigger as $$
  begin
    NEW.name_lower=lower(name);
    return NEW;
  end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger a_name_lower_trigger
  before insert or update on a
  for each row execute procedure name_lower_trigger();
create trigger b_name_lower_trigger
  before insert or update on b
  for each row execute procedure name_lower_trigger();
```

And create a foreign key constraint using these columns. But it would denormalize a database and waste storage and is ugly. It's much better to correct your data.

Comment: This is pretty much the only sensible solution. The only other alternative would be to implement your own foreign-key triggers doing a forced-lowercase comparison or some such.